# How can I do this, but with a changeable number of dice?

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops

How can I do this, but with a changeable number of dice? Which means that `all_dices` can have any length.

```
 for first_dice_number in all_dices[0]:
    for second_dice_number in all_dices[1]:
        for thrird_dice_number in all_dices[2]:
            result = first_dice_number+second_dice_number+thrird_dice_number
            results.append(result)
```

For clarification, `all_dices` looks like:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

This most likely is a noob question but I just can't figure it out.

The problem is that I don't want to put a 100 `for` loops inside each other.

Comment: 6^100 is infeasibly large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a (Cartesian) product of the sets of values.

```
from itertools import product

results = [sum(numbers) for numbers in product(*all_dices)]
```

For example:

```
>>> list(product([1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: in OP's case, all the factors are the same, so it might be preferable to use the `repeat` optional parameter rather than the splat operator.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is made for those things, put one loop in a function, and keep calling yourself until you do not have dices

```py
all_dices=[range(1,6),range(1,6),range(1,6),range(1,6)]

def flip(dicenum,totaluntilhere):
  if dicenum>len(all_dices)
    results.append(totaluntilhere+all_dices[dicenum]
  else
  for dice in all_dices[dicenum+1]:
    flip(dicenum+1,totaluntilhere+dice)

flip(-1,0)
```

I am not so good in python, but that's the idea

Comment: Recursion isn't the go-to technique in Python that it would be in other languages, due to the overhead of calling a user-defined function and the limited amount of stack space for chains of function calls. Prefer iterative solutions instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `itertools` solution is probably the best in Python, but another way to handle dice is to think about enumerating possible rolls of `n` dice as counting from 0 to 6^n -1 in base 6 (but using "digits" 1 to 6 rather than 0 to 5):

```
def decode(dice_code, num_dice):
    dice = []
    for _ in range(num_dice):
        dice_code,r = divmod(dice_code,6)
        dice.append(1+r)
    return dice
```

For example, `decode(0,5)` is `[1,1,1,1,1]` and `decode(7775,5)` is `[6,6,6,6,6]`. Just loop over `range(6**n)`, decoding as needed.